# Inserting into Postgres DB column with python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=name host=host user=user password=pass port=port")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open('big shot.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for key in data["permissions"]:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO permissions (name) VALUES (%s);", (key,))
conn.commit()
output = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM permissions")
print(output)
```

I have this that I'm trying to use to create new rows in my database, but it doesn't do anything. It doesn't return any errors, but it also doesn't write to my database, and output, obviously, returns "None" in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the data from the cursor:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM permissions")
data = cur.fetchall()
print(data)
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb, I did that and it output the same thing a bunch of times cuz I've run this so many times lmao